# Changing column name in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to change a column name in sql without having to recreate the table? 
I've tried alter table dbo.Conforming rename column [xxx] to [xxx] and it doesn't work.  any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

use [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID', 'TerrID', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

Comment: why do i need to use a stored procedure?  isn't there a straight one line of code to do this?

Comment: no. that's the way to do it. it's still one straight line of code :)